# Approximation of Sets of Finite Perimeter

Tags: calculus-of-variations, approximation-theory, geometric-measure-theory, bounded-variation

Fix an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $E$ is a measurable subset of $\Omega$, we may define the perimeter of $E$ in $\Omega$, denoted by $P(E;\Omega)$, to be

$$P(E;\Omega) = \sup_{\underset{||\phi||_{\infty} \leq 1}{\phi \in C^1_c(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)}} \int_E \mbox{div} \phi \, dx,$$

and when $P(E;\Omega) < +\infty$ we say that $E$ has finite perimeter in $\Omega$.

A basic property of any set of finite perimeter is that it may be approximated by sets with smooth boundary, in the following sense: for $E$ with $P(E;\Omega) < + \infty$, there exists a sequence $E_n$ such that $$\chi_{E_n} \xrightarrow{L^1} \chi_E$$ $$P(E_n; \Omega) \to P(E;\Omega),$$
where the $E_n = G_n \cap \Omega$ and the $G_n$ have smooth boundaries.

This is shown in Theorem 3.42 and Remark 3.43 of "Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems" by Ambrosio, Fusco, and Pallara. The basic argument involves first considering $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, approximating $\chi_E$ by a sequence $\{u_n\}$ of smooth functions, and then defining $E_n = \{ u_n > t\}$ for an appropriate choice of $t$. The coarea formula, together with the lower-semicontinuity of the perimeter functional, can combine to prove that $P(E_n;\Omega) \to P(E;\Omega)$. The precise choice of $t$ is mostly irrelevant -- Sard's theorem implies that for almost every $0 < t < 1$ the resulting $E_n$ have smooth boundary. For more general $\Omega$, one needs some sort of extension operator (so there are some modest regularity conditions on $\Omega$ for this to be true).

My question is this: is it possible to do the same sort of approximation, but with the additional constraint $$m(E_n) = m(E),$$ where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure? More specifically, are you aware of a result of this sort in the literature?

Comment: If $E$ is compactly contained in $\Omega$, then simple rescaling works. That is, replace $E_n$ with $\alpha_nE_n$ where $\alpha_n$ is chosen so that $m(\alpha_nE_n)=m(E)$. Since $\alpha_n\to 1$, the rescaled sets are compactly contained in $\Omega$ for large $n$; hence the perimeter is multiplied by a power of $\alpha_n$, and the desired  convergence holds. Aside: it's not a good idea to use $n$ both as an index and as dimension.

Comment: This should work: take $x$ in the reduced boundary $\mathcal{F}E$. For small $r$, remove the ball $B(x,r)$ from the original set $E$ obtaining $\tilde E=E\cap B(x,r)^c$. Approximate $\tilde E$ with smooth sets $\tilde E_h$ such that $\partial \tilde E_h\subset I_{\epsilon_h}(\partial \tilde E)$ where $\epsilon_h\to 0$ (F. Maggi, Sets of finite perimeter and geometric variational problems, Theorem 13.8). Then adjust the volume putting back a ball $B(x,tr)$ with $0<t<1$. There is enough space to insert the ball because $x$ is in $\mathcal F E$. Finally take a diagonal sequence as $r\to 0$.